# How to convert stored procedures written in SQL to Java. Got a reference of ANTLR

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, antlr, antlr4

I am completely new to Programming language translation and don't know how to start. I want to convert stored procedures written in PL/SQL to Java, to make our application database independent.

There are about 50 stored procedures, each having about 10000-15000 lines of code. I am looking for a way to automate this.

I have got a reference of ANTLR parser, and have found some parsers on GitHub, but have no clue, how to go about it.

Comment: Forget about this approach. Write it from scratch. You can use ANLR to extract SQLs out of procedures, table names from SQL to get some overview. But that's all. PS: I'm co-author of on of those parsers.

Comment: PL/SQL and Java are completely different languages, so your question is "how do I automatically re-write 500,000 LOC", which is impossible. You need to hire people.

Comment: @ibre5041 Are you saying that I should start writing a new parser or use an existing one? Will one parser convert the code from sql to java?

Comment: @Nidhi write the Java programs from scratch. Java uses Object oriented programming (OOP) and PL/SQL is a completely different animal. There is no efficient way to automate any of this. Start reading the PLSQL code and then build the Java programs from scratch. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

First of all you must know some theory, and also you have to learn something about ANTLR. The ANTLR parser will give you "only" AST (Abstract syntax tree), which is just a small 1st step. The rest is up to you. There is an article called "[Life after parsing](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html)" describing the problems with automatic translation. If you do not have an experience with this, you probably should not start this way.

You can use ANTRL for:

- generation of PL/SQL code call-tree. To get some overview of code's business logic.
- extract SQL statements from PL/SQL code
- extract table names from SQLs

This can give you some overview which "module" accesses particular tables.
You can also serialize the AST tree into some "fake" java code, where original PL/SQL will be stored as comments. But the rest it up to you. PL/SQL programming style is different from Java one.

PS: You will also find that some of Oracle's proprietary SQLs can not be easily translated into ISO SQL92, and some databases do not even support ISO SQL92 (or higher). So as I wrote before most of the work must be done manually. So maybe rewriting it from scratch is not so bad idea.

Comment: I second this. Given the *totally* different paradigms of Java and PL/SQL, even if you put a *lot* of effort into a converter, and somehow get it working after countless months of hard work, you'll end up with massively crappy Java code anyway, which will be unreadable for a human being. Just do it from scratch.